# ERROR PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “DECLARE”?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have below simple function where i am trying to have simple function with dynamic query
i.e sqlstatement (though in this example i have mentioned simple query)

```
create or replace
FUNCTION test_simple_func ( testVal IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN number IS
   total number(2) := 0;
  DECLARE @sqlstatement VARCHAR(MAX);
 BEGIN 
  SET @sqlstatement = 'Select * from employee'; 
  select count(*) INTO total from employee;
    RETURN total;
 END;
```

i am not getting whats wrong here?

Comment: This code is not in `Oracle` one its in `TSql`. I have posted a `Oracle` version of it check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is in Oracle Version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_simple_func(
        testVal IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN NUMBER
    AS
      total NUMBER;
        sqlstatement VARCHAR2(4000);
    BEGIN

      sqlstatement := 'Select * from employee';
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO total
      FROM employee;
      RETURN total;
    END;
```

And if you want to use as a dynamic query then you need to use `EXECUTE immediate`
like `EXECUTE immediate sqlstatement`

Answer (score 1):

Unlike SQL where the varchar limitation is 4000, the limitation in PL/SQL is around 32K

Otherwise, no declare in PL/SQL function. DECLARE is used for anonymous blocs in Oracle.

The correct synthax is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION test_simple_func ( testVal IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN number IS
   total number(2) := 0;
   sqlstatement VARCHAR(32000);
BEGIN 
  sqlstatement := 'Select * from employee'; 
  select count(*) INTO total from employee;
    RETURN total;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `declare` block should start before **all** the declarations:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION test_simple_func ( testVal IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN number IS
DECLARE -- right place for declare
   total number(2) := 0;
   sqlstatement VARCHAR(4000);
BEGIN 
  SET sqlstatement = 'Select * from employee'; 
  select count(*) INTO total from employee;
    RETURN total;
END;
```

Comment: Still issue. Here are complete errors Error(4,2): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior external language The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.

Comment: Error(15,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

Comment: line 4 is "Declare.." and line 15 is "END"

Answer (score 0):

As per my memory VARCHAR(MAX) is not supported by Oracle

Answer (score 0):

**This is a proper way to execute Dynamic Query**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_simple_func(
    testVal IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  total NUMBER(10) := 0;
  sqlstatement CLOB;
BEGIN
  sqlstatement := 'Select count(*) from employee';
  --select count(*) INTO total from employee;
  EXECUTE immediate sqlstatement INTO total;
  RETURN total;
END;
```